# timeAgoInWords error in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp "timeAgoInWords" function to display my time but here I found it is adding 12hrs in current time.

I don't understand how it calculate the time. I am using "UTC" timezone in my application. I printed my current time. Here is my code.

```
    $dt = '2014-09-11 02:03:10';
    $dtFormat = str_replace('on', '', $this->Time->timeAgoInWords(
                $dt,
                array('format' => 'F j, Y | h:i a' , 'end' => '+1 week')
    ));

    echo str_replace('|', 'at', $dtFormat); //Output: 12 hours, 7 minutes ago ()
    echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); //Output: 2014-09-11 02:10:33

    //Configuration in core.php in cakePHP
    Configure::write('Config.timezone', 'UTC');
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

here it should print only **"7 minutes ago"**. Why it is showing me 12 hours additional?

Comment: You're probably comparing your local time zone (I guess) with the UTC time.
I have the same problem if I do the same setting the timezone as you did, but everything works fine if I just don't set them.

Comment: No, it not works for me. I just tried to not set it but not works for me.

Comment: Jimit, are you in the UTC timezone? If not, which? Is there a chance that your local timezone is exactly twelve hours different that UTC?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins My local timezone is "Asia/Kolkata" but I have set in application to UTC timezone.

Comment: Use echo Configure::read('Config.timezone'); to check in view if timezone is not utc